# Can one install KVM on Windows?

Tags: windows, virtualization, kvm

Can one install KVM on a Windows system where Windows will be the host operating system?

I have searched a lot but every answer is about how one can install Windows as guest on KVM.

Answer (score 20):

No, it does not install on a windows system, because it is a linux kernel module.

Answer (score 8):

KVM is short for Kernel-based Virtual Machine. It's for Linux only.
You can use the similar solution - HAXM.
It's be supported by Windows 7 (32/64) or higher.
You can get details from here: https://github.com/intel/haxm

Comment: Unfortunately HAXM does not work with Ryzen CPUs. Hyper-V is required.

Answer (score 6):

Google ported KVM to Windows. The name is misleading. http://github.com/google/Android-emulator-hypervisor-driver-for-amd-processors

Answer (score 1):

You can run a linux VM on Windows, and then run most of the KVM toolchain inside it. But the core KVM depends having the Linux kernel running in baremetal. Without that, you're dependent on the qemu emulator, which should work in theory, albeit slowly. In practice, and maybe I didn't try hard enough, it didn't work for me.